# Why react component libraries prefer prop based styling

Tags: react-bootstrap, reactstrap, core-ui

If we are using react component libraries we need to pass style in props, how this aproach is helpful than setting bootstrap style inside className

Answer (score 0):

We can do bootstrap styling. There is nothing wrong with it, by writing className and giving bootstrap class name and everything.

But in react, we can create a component which means we can divide our App into smaller app and control the inside data through props and state. So by passing the style through props gives us more flexibility, we can customize the component design based on its data. I think this is the main feature that we can get.